# Getting data within <li> tag on Beautiful Soup or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to Extract the contents from the `<li>` tags

Website: http://snowload.atcouncil.org/index.php/component/vcpsnowload/item

I wanted to extract contents like for different cities by entering in the address.

```
Query Date :
August 04, 2017
Address :
gilbert
Latitude :
33.3528264
Longitude :
-111.789027
Elevation :
0 Feet
Elevation Limitation: ASCE 7* Ground Snow Load
Elevation ≤ 2,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is 0 psf
```

Please find the  approach which I tried to extract the contents.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/index.php/component/vcpsnowload/item")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
div = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'span5'})
print div.text
```

Problem which am facing is like its not getting extracted completely only Query Date is only extracted.

Also i tried with different parsers like `'html.parser'` ,`'html5lib'`,`'lxml'`which gives the same result.

Please try to give some solution if it can be done with Selenium and Python.

Comment: what is the main problem? your code prints out the text you want, You maybe did a bad search? If you want automated search for different cities maybe selenium is a better choice. Your code does not search for different querys. Since the city name is not in the url, you can not accomplish it like this

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HTTP POST method and send the location in the data e.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

data = {'optionCoordinate': '2','coordinate_address': 'gilbert'}

page = requests.post("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/index.php/component/vcpsnowload/item", data = data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
div = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'span5'})
print (div.text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))
```

There seems to be some characters my terminal cant print so I added

```
.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

Updated:

from there you can get the li elements:

```
for li in div.find_all('li'):
    print (li.text)
```

Updated again to write to CSV:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('csvfile.csv','w') as csv:
    for city in ['gilbert', 'tuscon', 'nogales']:
        data = {'optionCoordinate': '2','coordinate_address': city}
        page = requests.post("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/index.php/component/vcpsnowload/item", data = data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
        div = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'span5'})
        row = ""
        for li in div.find_all('li'):
            t = li.find(['span', 'p'])
            if t is not None:
                row += '"' + t.text + '",'
        csv.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: Thats the answer! One (small) note. If you want to automate this process, make a list of city names and put the rest of the code in a `for/while/map` loop.

Comment: Could you please explain data = {'optionCoordinate': '2','coordinate_address': 'gilbert'} this line. what this optioncoordinate will do ??

Comment: optioncoordinate is set by the calling form on http://snowload.atcouncil.org/ it is either 1 for Latitude and Longitude queries or 2 for Address as we are using here or 3 for Alaska

Comment: How to save this output text into csv file ??

Comment: Also i need till "Elevation ≤ 2,000 feet: Ground Snow Load is 0 psf". How to do that.Please kindly help me.

Comment: Updated to write to csv

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the text within each `<li></li>` you are targeting on that page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from requests import get

site = "http://snowload.atcouncil.org/index.php/component/vcpsnowload/item"
req = get(site)
soup = BS(req.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('ul', attrs={'class', 'map-info'})
list_items = div.find_all('li')

for li in list_items:
    print(li.text)
```

Comment: @vishal Edited.

Comment: @AMagoon I think his problem are more the missing values than printing the correct part. His code gives the same output...

Comment: @hansTheFranz I just tested `soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'span5'})` and realized it does indeed work. Still not sure what OP's primary issue is.

Answer (score 0):

**Automated Solution to Extract the contents within `li` tags**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://snowload.atcouncil.org/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="adminForm"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/div[2]/label""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="coordinate_address"]""").click()
cities = ['pheonix']
for city in cities:
    print (city)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="coordinate_address"]').send_keys(city)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="adminForm"]/fieldset/div/div[2]/button').click()
x = driver.current_url
#print x
Data = {'optionCoordinate': '2','coordinate_address': cities}
page = requests.post(x, data = Data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser') 
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'span5'})
for li in div.find_all('li'):
    y = (li.text)
    print y

driver.close()
```